# Azure B2C: When should I define an Azure Active Directory technical identity for custom policies?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

While taking a look at the [base custom policy](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml) for local accounts, I noticed that the Azure Active Directory (AAD) was also declared in addition to local accounts.

Do you actually need to include AAD when using local accounts or would omitting it be fine?  If I can omit, what features would I miss if I don't use ADD?

And if you could omit AAD, when why does the example file use AAD?

Comment: Thanks @Joseph. Additional information is provided into the AAD B2C FAQ (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/faq?tabs=app-reg-ga)

Comment: Be more specific, there are tons of references to AAD. You can link to a specific line or paste the relevant line as reference in your post. You can find an explanation here on what it’s all for https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/azureadb2ccommunity.io/wiki/LocalAccount-Sign-In-and-Sign-Up-policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to the `AAD-Common` technical profile - this is the heart of Azure AD B2C. If you omit `AAD-Common`, nothing in B2C will work.

Local accounts use very heavily the AAD-Common. Because, at the end, everything is saved in the local "directory". Additionally, `login-NonInteractive` technical profile, is the core of Azure AD B2C local accounts.